# Cannot activate Google Maps Android API v2 on Google API Console

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to active Google Maps Android API v2 on the Google API console. It does not work.

If I try in the new console it just gets stuck on

> Enabling Google Maps Android API v2

and nothing more happens.

If I try in the old console, I get the error

> An error has occurred. Please retry later.

I have tried logging out and in and other browsers too.

Does any one recognize this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you are lucky: I just managed to activate the service by first creating a new project in the console, and then activating the service.